# how to make a method return a double

Tags: java, methods, tostring, rational-numbers

i have the following code and getNom and getdenom are both integers for example 2 and 5. How come I am getting the output of 0.0 here and not 0.4? Thank you.

```
public double divide() {
        double number = getNom() / getDenom();
        rn.toString(number);
        return number;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `getNom()` and `getDenom()` are operating correctly?

Comment: More specifically, what type does `getNom()` and `getDenom()` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
`double number = getNom() / (double)getDenom();`

Comment: This worked, thank you. I was not aware of using casts!

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is use `double number = getNom() * 1.0 / getDenom();`